# MySQL nested update

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have got a database with many wrong entries in the field `timestamp` (set at `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, what I want to do is to update this field with the last valid timestamp. I've tried with this query, unfortunately with no success (the syntax is not accepted):

```
UPDATE `scontrini` s1
SET s1.`timestamp` = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 s2.`timestamp`
        FROM `scontrini` s2
        WHERE s2.`timestamp` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s2.`id` < s1.`id`
        ORDER BY s2.`id` DESC)
WHERE `scontrini`.`timestamp`= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Some solutions suggest using an `inner join`, but I am not testing the equality of some value.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I changed the query as suggested to:

```
UPDATE `scontrini` as s1
SET s1.`timestamp` = 
    (SELECT s2.`timestamp`
        FROM `scontrini` as  s2
        WHERE s2.`timestamp` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s2.`id` < s1.`id`
        ORDER BY s2.`id` DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE s1.`timestamp`= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

But I still got error messages.

Static analysis:
1. Near `SELECT`: a new statement has been found, but there is no delimiter between this statement and the previous one.
2. Near the 2nd `WHERE`: this type of clause has already been examined
3. Near the 2nd `WHERE`: statement not recognized.

MySQL error message:

```
#1093 - Table 's1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post the error message please.

Comment: `top` is not supported. Use `limit`

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

TOP is used in SQL server not in MySQL. use `LIMIT` in end of your sub query to limit number of rows returned.

```
UPDATE `scontrini` s1
SET s1.`timestamp` = 
    (SELECT s2.`timestamp`
        FROM `scontrini` s2
        WHERE s2.`timestamp` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s2.`id` < s1.`id`
        ORDER BY s2.`id` DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE `scontrini`.`timestamp`= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: You are correct, but I still got syntax errors. See updated  question.

Answer (score 0):

Use max()  and a proper date format

```
 UPDATE `scontrini` s1
 SET s1.`timestamp` = 
 (
    SELECT max(s2.`timestamp`)
    FROM `scontrini` s2
    WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(s2`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') <> 
                    '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s2.`id`< s1.`id`
 )
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(s1.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Just want to know. Already `s1` is set alias for `\`scontrini\``, again using `\`scontrini\`.\`timestamp\`` won't cause any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE `scontrini` as s1
SET s1.`timestamp` = 
    (SELECT s2.`timestamp`
        FROM `scontrini` s2
        WHERE s2.`timestamp` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND s2.`id` < s1.`id`
        ORDER BY s2.`timestamp` DESC limit 0,1)
WHERE `s1`.`timestamp`= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```